# recv принимает сообщения без пробела

Tags: c++, winsock

Приветствую, проблема с recv.
Принимает сообщения слитно в чем ошибка, как исправить?
Если заранее определить как здесь, все корректно отправляется
Хочется ставить \n после каждого принятия, но тогда он принимает каждое слово которое было введено через пробел, на новую строку

```
//Send
char buff[512] = "Helloy client\n";
int sen = send(AcceptSocket, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
while(1)
{
    int rec = recv(AcceptSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    printf("%s", buff);
    scanf("%s",&buff);
    send(AcceptSocket, buff,sizeof(buff), 0);
};     
Привет друг! //Отсылаем данные
Приветдруг! // Такие данные придут клиенту или же если отправлены наоборот
```

Аналогично и с Клиентом

Comment: перепишите вопрос. Приведите примеры ввода и вывода. Приведите реальный пример (судя по вопросу, Вы привели код, в котором все работает).

Comment: Допустим если написать 2 слова
Привет друг!
То он считает как:
Приветдруг!
И т.д что у клиента, что у сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала - хоть это и не к вашему вопросу - передавайте и нулевой символ -

```
int sen = send(AcceptSocket, buff, strlen(buff) +1, 0);
                                               ^^^
```

или потом его дописывайте..

А у вас проблема в том, что `scanf("%s",&buff);` читает **одно слово**, а не строку целиком. Используйте, например, [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets):

```
fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin);
```

Comment: Можно пример с fgets, не особо понял как его использовать

Comment: `fgets()` будет долго ждать, если соединение не оборвано, и нет в потоке `'n`.

Comment: @0andriy Да-да, конечно, и `scanf` тоже работает по сети... Вы хоть смотрите, что написано, для начала...

Comment: Дополнил описание `fgets`...

Comment: Сори, не правильно сам делал, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Как вы это определили, что не отсылает? Потому что теперь не корежит введенное вами? А разве вы не этого добивались?

Comment: Все все работает, огромное спасибо)
Просто я случайно удалил строку с recv и не заметил
Много уже мучался с этой проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после `recv(AcceptSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);` объявить `string ResponseBuffer(buff);` и используйте дальше ResponseBuffer со всеми фичами string. У меня при такой практике проблем не возникало.

Comment: все @Harry ответ помог
решено, просто я малех запрограммировался)
Спасибо и вам)